# Trigger event when a subtotal changes (excel, vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a Dashboard and want it to be updated anytime an user filters the RawData sheet. I'm trying to create an eventlistener which calls the following macro:

```
Public Sub CompAllSecUpdate()
Dim wbTarget As Worksheet

Set wbTarget = Sheets("EDMainTable")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'clear Maintable
    wbTarget.Range("A2:L1000").Clear

        EDMainTable
            SecoColumn
            ThirdColumn
            FourthColumn
            fithAsixColumn
            SevANinColumn
            EigATenColumn
        FTEPTE
        Contracts
        EDAnniversary
        EDFemale
        EDMale
        EDAbsencereason
        'EDInternalChange
        EDStarter
        EDleavers
        EDBirthday
        BirthSort

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This macro should get activated as soon as the subtotal of the RawData sheet changes. It's a workaround to get the my Dashboard updated, when the RawData is filtered.

Until now I wrote the following code which does not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 30 Then

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Call CompAllSecUpdate

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End If
End Sub
```

The question is: How do I get my macro to work, after the RawData sheet is filtered?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event, which would fire when a `SUBTOTAL` formula recalcs.

Comment: I implemented the SecUpdate sub into the Worksheet_Calc event, but I got an error saying 'Object required'. Atleast it reacted. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: There's no `Target` in `Worksheet_Calculate`. Do you have any other formulas on that sheet, or is there only a `SUBTOTAL` one?

Comment: yes, updated it

Comment: okay, i know what you mean, but do not really know what I need to put in there. Just declare Target as Range?

Comment: I have lots of formulas on this sheet, that is why I defined the specific cell

Comment: With `Worksheet_Calculate`, if you want to check a specific cell, you need a different approach. Let me find a good link. One option is to basically store the old value in a `Public` variable (populated in the `Workbook_Open` event), and then compare the new value to the old value.

Comment: Hi, this worked excellent. Thank you very much!!